# SQL Syntax Error in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
CREATE TABLE COMPUTER
    SerialNumber Numeric NOT NULL,
    Make Char(12) NOT NULL,
    Model Char(24) NOT NULL,
    ProcessorType Char(24) NULL,
    ProcessorSpeed Numeric NOT NULL,
    MainMemory Char(15) NOT NULL,
    DiskSize Char(15) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT COMPUTER_PK PRIMΑRY KEY(SerialNumber);
```

Returns an error (highlights the first numeric statement in the second line). 
What is the problem?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? You need another open and close paren in there.

Comment: You also misspelled `PRIMARY`.

Comment: Numeric is a synonym for DECIMAL. Are you sure that your primary key should be a DECIMAL? Why you do not use the specific names provided for Access [Jet Sql Data Types](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/sql-data-types-HP001032248.aspx)

Comment: @Steve Numeric creates type Double, not Decimal in MS Access. I am afraid I think that is not a useful article, several of those types will not work at all in QBE and there are much better names for the others when running in MS Access. The latest version of the common database for MS Access is ACE, not Jet.

Answer (score 4):

I would try using parentheses ([used in documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb177893%28v=office.12%29.aspx))

```
CREATE TABLE computer (
    ...
);
```

Example from documentation:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(FirstName CHAR, LastName CHAR, 
DateOfBirth DATETIME, 
CONSTRAINT MyTableConstraint UNIQUE 
(FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth));
```

As mentioned in the comments, you misspelled `PRIMARY`.

Comment: The trailing semi colon needs to be outside of the parenthesis.

Comment: Got to love those obvious fixes for mistakes that happen because you're typing to fast. Thanks for the help. I fixed it. After adding the missing parentheses it pointed out the misspelling.